# Query result in the error response in the JQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, json

I have a problem, clicking in a < tr > of a table I call a javascript function which in turn calls a function in php to get data in a database. The click on the table row works, sql works, and from the console.log command I know there is an answer in reponseText. but it does not work and I get the error back, I'll post the code. I hope you can help me.

file config.php

```
//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','toor');

try{
    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user card, pass in the database connection
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cards.php');
$card = new card($db);
```

file cards.php

```
<?php

class card
{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function view_card_id($id)
    {
        $rows = array();

        $statement = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM card_details WHERE card_id = :card_id');
        $statement->execute(array(':card_id' => $id));

        $numrows = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($numrows < 1) {
            $this->error = "Error";
            return false;
        } else {
            $statement->bindColumn("card_id", $cid);
            $statement->bindColumn("a", $a);
            $statement->bindColumn("b", $b);

            $rows[] = array('card_id' => $numrows['card_id'], 'a' => $numrows['a'], 'b' => $numrows['b']);

            while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
                $row = array('card_id' => $cid, 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        }

    }
```

file index.php

```
<?php

//include config
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config.php');

?>

html code ....

<script src="/js/Cards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

file Cards.js

```
$('#table-cards tr').click(function() {
var id = $(this).find("a").text();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/classes/cardsFunc.php',
        dataType:'text',
        data: {functionname: "view_card", id: id },
        success: function(response){
            //Use response
            alert("Server echo: "+response);
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            alert("Error: "+msg);
        }
    });

 });
```

In the Cards.js file, once the $ .ajax function is called, it does not return to success but to error, but in the console.log I see the array of the executed query under the responseText entry.

that is, in the error response, I see the result of the query, which in theory should be in the response of success.

I also tried to use

```
$.post('/classes/cardsFunc.php', { functionname: 'view_card', id: id }, function(data){

});
```

but nothing

file cardsFunc.php

```
<?php

//include config
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config.php');

if(isset($_POST['functionname']) && $_POST['functionname'] == "view_card"){

    $card_view = $card->view_card_id($_POST['id']);
    print json_encode($card_view);

}


?>
```

thank you for the time you have dedicated to me

I noticed that if I recreate the connection to the db in the file cardsFunc.php, everything works, but I do not understand why, since everything is in the config.php file.
Like this:

file cardsFunc.php

```
<?php

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','toor');

try{
    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user card, pass in the database connection
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cards.php');
$card = new card($db);

if(isset($_POST['functionname']) && $_POST['functionname'] == "view_card"){

    $card_view = $card->view_card_id($_POST['id']);
    print json_encode($card_view);

}


?>
```

Comment: and the error you are getting is...?

Comment: You have issues in the PHP probably. You should attempt to isolate _only_ the PHP scripts by submitting a POST request directly to the endpoint without going through the complexity of JavaScript stuff - search online for API testing software. Alternatively, you could starting debugging with xDebug. Alternatively, you could have people on the internet tell you that `$card` isn't defined in cardsFunc.php :P

Comment: $card is defined in config.php

Comment: @Stefano You have $user defined there. Card seems undefined. Update the code if you didn't... You can easily debug by using network tab and var_dump, die;

Comment: @revengeance I was wrong to look at the code sorry! I put it bad but it does not work,

Comment: @Stefano Do you have data in database? Maybe it returned 0 records and false after.

Comment: @revengeance yes I have data, I noticed that if I recreate the connection to the db in the file cardsFunc.php, everything works, but I do not understand why, since everything is in the config.php file

Comment: I think that you need to include $db in the class using GLOBAL

Comment: @Tom can you show me how?

Comment: You can find a better solution here https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oo-ep2/one-db-conn-with-property

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your folder structure?